# How can I know if I need more instances?

Tags: devops

How do I know if I need more instances?

At the moment my setup is the following. I have a wordpress website running LAMP server on a micro instance with Cloudfront. Now recently this website has been getting quite a lot of traffic. Think 100-150k pageviews a day with 150-200 visitors simultaneously at peak times.

At the moment both the database and all the static files are in the server itself, but that's really not an issue as they're served from Cloudfront anyway. I could move the database to an RDS instance and the statics to S3 and then set up a scaling stack. But before going into this I would like to know if this is a solution to anything, or even if I have a problem. The website seems slightly sluggish, but I'm not even sure where that's coming from.

So my question is: how to I determine if I even have a problem? Is the "sluggishness" just my imagination? If I do, it's not something very obvious, but when the number of visitors becomes large, even a seemingly imperceptible slow down might hurt your metrics.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, first you need to monitoring your web application performance with some tools, such as [new relic](http://newrelic.com/php/wordpress). then add feedback on your site, your users can send feedback to you when they feel visit your site slowly.